# What determines launched gui for powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have two shortcuts. One created in Win10 and copied to my Win7 home pc. The other I created with my Win7. They reference the same `powershell.exe` with the same path. Their properties seem identical. When I launch 1st one (the "Win10-one") it launches in PS gui window with my custom colors. When I launch the native Win7 shortcut it starts a cmd-like ui. I want Win7 shortcut to start Powershell gui not cmd. How do I control it?

Upd: not to misuse GUI term here are screens of what I mean by windows

powershell-like
[image]

cmd-like
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean from your question, what command are you using?

Comment: I just double-click shortcut on desktop. It has no commands attached, it just launches `powershell.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 things here when you right click on top left of powershell windows context menu appear this context menu have some item 2 of that is :

1. Default  : 
   if you use this item to customize your GUI it will be save for all of the time and all of powershell that you open .
2. Properties :
   if you customize this item you will get GUI only for this version and architecture of powershell

then try to use default item to customize powershell

Answer (score 0):

Custom colours for a console executable are held in the shortcut (thus one can have multiple different shortcuts to the same executable with different settings: this is quite useful when you regularly use multiple instances concurrently).

Thus the one created on Windows 7 will have the customisations you did before copying but the one created on Windows 10 will have only the customisations you did for that shortcut.

PS. What do you mean by "PS gui window": PowerShell.exe is only going to open a console subsystem window. PowerShell ISE (which is a GUI application) is a different executable.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you're getting two different things happening.  Without the shortcup properties to check we can only assume:

1. When you run PowerShell in one case (Win7 I think), it's basically running a CMD prompt to call the powershell.exe at that location, why it's doing this I don't know.
2. The other one is calling the powershell.exe using the path provided, and launches the PowerShell prompt as you would expect (blue background).

If you go to "run" or open a CMD prompt, then put in `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` you'll get the two different behaviors.